# How can I define a custom alphabet order for comparing and sorting strings in go?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, go

**Please read to the bottom before marking this as duplicate**

I would like to be able to sort an array of strings (or a slice of structs based on one string value) alphabetically, but *based on a custom alphabet or unicode letters*.

Most times people advise using a collator that supports different pre-defined locales/alphabets. (See [this answer for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215852/how-to-sort-non-english-strings)), but what can be done for rare languages/alphabets that are not available in these locale bundles?

The language I would like to use **is not available** [in the list of languages](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language#Tag) supported and usable by Golangs's [collate](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/collate), so *I need to be able to define a custom alphabet, or order of Unicode characters/runes for sorting.*

Others suggest translate the strings into an english/ASCII sortable alphabet first, and then sort that. That's what's been suggested by a similar question in [this solution done in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718597/8620945) or [this solution in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778202/how-can-i-sort-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-non-standard-alphabet). **But surely there must be a more efficient way to do this with Go.**

Is it possible to create a [Collator](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/collate#Collator) in Go that uses a custom alphabet/character set? Is that what [func NewFromTable](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/collate#NewFromTable) is for?

It seems that I should be able to use the [Reorder](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/collate#Reorder) function but it looks like this is *not yet implemented in the language?* The [source code](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/collate/option.go#L208) shows this:

```
func Reorder(s ...string) Option {
    // TODO: need fractional weights to implement this.
    panic("TODO: implement")
}
```

How can I **define a custom alphabet order for comparing and sorting strings** in go?

Comment: Have you ever checked sort package ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the sort package, but I can't see an option to use a custom alphabet for sorting strings.

Comment: Use sort.StringSlice struct and check if sort works for your alphabet or not

Comment: "How can I define a custom alphabet order for comparing and sorting strings in go?" Why not implement Reorder and help Marcel finish golang.org/x/text/collate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note beforehand:**

The following solution has been cleaned up and optimized, and published as a reusable library here: [`github.com/icza/abcsort`](https://github.com/icza/abcsort).

Using `abcsort`, custom-sorting a string slice (using a custom alphabet) is as simple as:

```
sorter := abcsort.New("bac")

ss := []string{"abc", "bac", "cba", "CCC"}
sorter.Strings(ss)
fmt.Println(ss)

// Output: [CCC bac abc cba]
```

Custom-sorting a slice of structs by one of the struct field is like:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

ps := []Person{{Name: "alice", Age: 21}, {Name: "bob", Age: 12}}
sorter.Slice(ps, func(i int) string { return ps[i].Name })
fmt.Println(ps)

// Output: [{bob 12} {alice 21}]
```

Original answer follows:

---

We can implement custom sorting that uses a custom alphabet. We just need to create the appropriate `less(i, j int) bool` function, and the [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package will do the rest.

Question is how to create such a `less()` function?

Let's start by defining the custom alphabet. Convenient way is to create a `string` that contains the letters of the custom alphabet, enumerated (ordered) from smallest to highest. For example:

```
const alphabet = "bca"
```

Let's create a map from this alphabet, which will tell the weight or order of each letter of our custom alphabet:

```
var weights = map[rune]int{}

func init() {
    for i, r := range alphabet {
        weights[r] = i
    }
}
```

<sup>(Note: `i` in the above loop is the byte index, not the `rune` index, but since both are monotone increasing, both will do just fine for rune weight.)</sup>

Now we can create our `less()` function. To have "acceptable" performance, we should avoid converting the input `string` values to byte or rune slices. To do that, we can call aid from the [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString) function which decodes the first `rune` of a `string`.

So we do the comparison rune-by-rune. If both runes are letters of the custom alphabet, we may use their weights to tell how they compare to each other. If at least one of the runes are not from our custom alphabet, we will fallback to simple numeric rune comparisons.

If 2 runes at the beginning of the 2 input strings are equal, we proceed to the next runes in each input string. We may do this my slicing the input strings: slicing them does not make a copy, it just returns a new string header that points to the data of the original strings.

All right, now let's see the implementation of this `less()` function:

```
func less(s1, s2 string) bool {
    for {
        switch e1, e2 := len(s1) == 0, len(s2) == 0; {
        case e1 && e2:
            return false // Both empty, they are equal (not less)
        case !e1 && e2:
            return false // s1 not empty but s2 is: s1 is greater (not less)
        case e1 && !e2:
            return true // s1 empty but s2 is not: s1 is less
        }

        r1, size1 := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s1)
        r2, size2 := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s2)

        // Check if both are custom, in which case we use custom order:
        custom := false
        if w1, ok1 := weights[r1]; ok1 {
            if w2, ok2 := weights[r2]; ok2 {
                custom = true
                if w1 != w2 {
                    return w1 < w2
                }
            }
        }
        if !custom {
            // Fallback to numeric rune comparison:
            if r1 != r2 {
                return r1 < r2
            }
        }

        s1, s2 = s1[size1:], s2[size2:]
    }
}
```

Let's see some trivial tests of this `less()` function:

```
pairs := [][2]string{
    {"b", "c"},
    {"c", "a"},
    {"b", "a"},
    {"a", "b"},
    {"bca", "bac"},
}
for _, pair := range pairs {
    fmt.Printf("\"%s\" < \"%s\" ? %t\n", pair[0], pair[1], less(pair[0], pair[1]))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zs9rmH_PIcX)):

```
"b" < "c" ? true
"c" < "a" ? true
"b" < "a" ? true
"a" < "b" ? false
"bca" < "bac" ? true
```

And now let's test this `less()` function in an actual sorting:

```
ss := []string{
    "abc",
    "abca",
    "abcb",
    "abcc",
    "bca",
    "cba",
    "bac",
}
sort.Slice(ss, func(i int, j int) bool {
    return less(ss[i], ss[j])
})
fmt.Println(ss)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DASHfWGkuDS)):

```
[bca bac cba abc abcb abcc abca]
```

Again, if performance is important to you, you should not use [`sort.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice) as that has to use reflection under the hood, but rather create your own slice type that implements [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface), and in your implementation you can tell how to do it without using reflection.

This is how it could look like:

```
type CustStrSlice []string

func (c CustStrSlice) Len() int           { return len(c) }
func (c CustStrSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return less(c[i], c[j]) }
func (c CustStrSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i] }
```

When you want to sort a string slice using the custom alphabet, simply convert your slice to `CustStrSlice`, so it can be passed directly to [`sort.Sort()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) (this type conversion does not make a copy of the slice or its elements, it just changes the type information):

```
ss := []string{
    "abc",
    "abca",
    "abcb",
    "abcc",
    "bca",
    "cba",
    "bac",
}
sort.Sort(CustStrSlice(ss))
fmt.Println(ss)
```

Output of the above is again (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HGHny7ASYsh)):

```
[bca bac cba abc abcb abcc abca]
```

**Some things to note:**

The default string comparison compares strings byte-wise. That is, if the input strings contain invalid UTF-8 sequences, the actual bytes will still be used.

Our solution is different in this regard, as we decode runes (we have to because we use a custom alphabet in which we allow runes that are not necessarily mapped to bytes 1-to-1 in UTF-8 encoding). This means if the input is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, the behavior might not be consistent with the default ordering. But if your inputs are valid UTF-8 sequences, this will do what you expect it to do.

**One last note:**

We've seen how a string slice could be custom-sorted. If we have a slice of structs (or a slice of pointers of structs), the sorting algorithm (the `less()` function) may be the same, but when comparing elements of the slice, we have to compare fields of the elements, not the struct elements themselves.

So let's say we have the following struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p *Person) String() string { return fmt.Sprint(*p) }
```

<sup>(The `String()` method is added so we'll see the actual contents of the structs, not just their addresses...)</sup>

And let's say we want to apply our custom sorting on a slice of type `[]*Person`, using the `Name` field of the `Person` elements. So we simply define this custom type:

```
type PersonSlice []*Person

func (p PersonSlice) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p PersonSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return less(p[i].Name, p[j].Name) }
func (p PersonSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

And that's all. The rest is the same, for example:

```
ps := []*Person{
    {Name: "abc"},
    {Name: "abca"},
    {Name: "abcb"},
    {Name: "abcc"},
    {Name: "bca"},
    {Name: "cba"},
    {Name: "bac"},
}
sort.Sort(PersonSlice(ps))
fmt.Println(ps)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uMrBdOgyge3)):

```
[{bca 0} {bac 0} {cba 0} {abc 0} {abcb 0} {abcc 0} {abca 0}]
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. Go and the community are truly a cut above.

Comment: Also do you mind briefly adding how this would be done with an **array/slice of structs with a string field**? Using slice.Sort() similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000001/8620945) ? Thank you so much for your help, and I'm sure this will be a useful question to others.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect, it would be nice if this could all be wrapped in a concise function in the `sort` package (where all someone had to do was define a custom alphabet and sort, but maybe that's a little too edge case. :-))

Comment: @AdamD This custom sorting can be wrapped in a utility lib, which I have just published at [`github.com/icza/abcsort`](https://github.com/icza/abcsort). See edited answer for a simple usage example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `table_test.go` [1] as a starting point, I came up with the following. The
real work is being done by `Builder.Add` [2]:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/text/collate"
   "golang.org/x/text/collate/build"
)

type entry struct {
   r rune
   w int
}

func newCollator(ents []entry) (*collate.Collator, error) {
   b := build.NewBuilder()
   for _, ent := range ents {
      err := b.Add([]rune{ent.r}, [][]int{{ent.w}}, nil)
      if err != nil { return nil, err }
   }
   t, err := b.Build()
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
   return collate.NewFromTable(t), nil
}
```

Result:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   a := []entry{
      {'a', 3}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 1},
   }
   c, err := newCollator(a)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   x := []string{"alfa", "bravo", "charlie"}
   c.SortStrings(x)
   fmt.Println(x) // [charlie bravo alfa]
}
```

1. https://github.com/golang/text/blob/3115f89c/collate/table_test.go
2. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/collate/build#Builder.Add